# Best Books or tutorials to be CakePHP Advanced Programmer

Tags: php, cakephp

I started reading **Apress Beginning CakePHP From Novice to Professional 2008**

But I was wondering if there are any other books I should read or Important tutorials I should be doing to be able to build a complete, stable CakePHP project.

Simply put, What did you do to get better in CakePHP development, your footsteps and recommendations.

I'm coming from a Java, C#.NET Background. I also did the Linda.com Video Course for Learning PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best resource is the Cakephp tutorial:

[Tutorials & Examples](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1527/Tutorials-Examples)

You can find the published books here:

[Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=cakephp&x=0&y=0)

For advanced tips:

[Super Awesome Advanced CakePHP Tips](http://www.pseudocoder.com/free-cakephp-book/)

No doubt you have to understand how PHP works first.

I suggest you choose a simple project you already did with another language/framework and try to recreate it with Cakephp